# Get div to be on the right of my sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay so i working on a portfolio site for myself as i am a graphic designer. I have a side bar currently with some essential info for my site and its always there. What i want is for my "portfolio section" to be next to it on the right. I created both in separate hmtl files just so i could fine tune them, now i want take the 'portfolio' code and paste it into the other html code, the problem when i do it and move all my css over nothing shows up.

the filtering shows up and i can kinda get it to be in the right spot but the portfolio images i cant get to show up.

Here is where im at with the code pasted in but cant seem to get the images to show: https://jsfiddle.net/5g15jzwt/ (the filtering selections are at the bottom, they should be at the top)

Here is my design, this is what im trying to get to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFebj.jpg

When i check to see whats wrong with firbug it says the .container div and the .portfoliolist div have heights of zero.

```
.container { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 940px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;  
 float: right;
 }
```

I hope this enough info to help, i cant seem to get other pages to work in jsfiddle to show you where im at. If you need anything else to help, just let me know and ill see what i can do. Also i know the code could be done a little ore efficiently in some places, im not the best just trying to make do

Thank you in advance

Comment: The imgur link is broken, cant see the design you want to achieve

Comment: @surajck here ya go sorry about that will change it in post too http://imgur.com/a/96RlE

Comment: Your media queries aren't properly capturing all the elments that need to be adjusted. There are a lot of elements which you've given fixed widths of 270px in your sidebar. I'd suggest that you use %'s for your widths of the two main elements "sidebar" (25% for instance) and "container" (75% for instance) right off the bat. Then every element within them if you must define a width set them to 100%. It will make it much easier for you down the line with your media queries to only adjust one width instead of many different elements with the same width.

Comment: Unless you're using a polyfill for [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components), `<wrapper>` is not a valid HTML5 tag.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, some of your div are not closed, you just open them.
For example, you open sidebar, but never close it. So instead of:

```
<div id="sidebar">

<div id="header">
    <img id="logo" class="my-logo" src="images/logo.svg"/>
    <h1>Warren Breedlove</h1>
</div>
```

You might want to do:

```
<div id="header">
    <img id="logo" class="my-logo" src="images/logo.svg"/>
    <h1>Warren Breedlove</h1>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    /* YOUR SIDEBAR CODE HERE */
</div> /* This closes the div */
```

Look at how to use div and make sure they don't overlap: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

Comment: This is comment and not an answer. Please [earn 50 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) and comment appropriately.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt at converting your comment to an answer by including code examples but in the end is it an actual answer to the problem? Which is essentially placing two `<div>` side-by-side.

Comment: I think it is. But I'll gladly take your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle with your Sidebar and Container appearing side by side as I imagine you intended.

https://jsfiddle.net/0m67qu4z/2/

The solution is based off of the comment I made to your original question. There were a number of different changes made to the CSS of this - all on width values. The most important ones were these;

```
#sidebar{
 height: 720px;
 width: 25%; /* changed to % */
 background-color: #fbfbfb;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
}

#info {
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 border-radius:5px;             
 background:#fcf8e3;
 border:1px solid  #fbeed5;
 width:95%;  /* Changed to % */
 max-width:900px;
 margin:0 auto 40px auto;
 font-family: roboto;
 font-size:12px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container { 
position: relative; 
width: 70%; /*changed to %*/
margin: 0 auto; 
 margin-left:20px; /* gave you a little room between the two elements */
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;    
float: left;  /*changed to float left */
}

/* #Tablet (Portrait) */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    .container {
      width: 70%; /*changed to %*/
    }
 }
```

Something else i forgot to mention is if you inspect element/firebug your code - your wrapper shows up as 0 x 0. Essentially it doesn't occupy any space. If you add

```
wrapper {
  display:table;
}
```

It will properly assign the width and height that you want to it.

Comment: this seemed to work a little. It gets it to the right place, i guess my only problem now is with the .portfoliolist div. It wont show any of the work. If i check it in firebug it says its height is 0. Im not sure why

Comment: @WarrenBreedlove ya there is a lot of little things that you need to tweak across the board in order to get things working how you want. This is meant to point you in the right direction with the over arching framework and now you can finesse the elements inside your main containers and get them displaying how you want.

Comment: @WarrenBreedlove that's because this rule `#portfoliolist .portfolio` has `display: none;`. Your content is hidden and doesn't take up any space so `#portfoliolist` has no height.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a flexbox solution. I'm using some pseudo code instead of yours to help simplify things and hopefully makes it easier to see what's going on.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: indianred;
}
aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: white;
}
aside nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
aside a {
  padding: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem;
}
aside p {
  margin-top: auto;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 1000px; /* <= for demo, mimic content height */
  padding: 0 2rem;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
section nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
section nav a {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  line-height: 60px;
}
section nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>
  
  <p>Copyright ©</p>
  
</aside>

<section> 

  <header>
    
    <nav>
      <a href="#">All</a>
      <a href="#">Logos</a>
      <a href="#">School Work</a>
    </nav>
    
  </header>
  
  <main>
    <!-- place work example markup here -->
  </main>
  
</section>
```